# Oracle Map with OBIEE 12C

Tags: obiee, oracle-map-viewer

I work with obiee 12c , I want to know if it is possible to modify DATA OF the oracle Map, because it can not found all city

Answer (score 0):

What precise data set are you using? "Oracle Map" doens't mean much. Do you mean the free (as in "free beer") demo data set? You will never get full or detailed data for free. Those are payable products you need to buy and license.

Comment: I'm talking about default map of oracle, in fact it does not contain the cities I need

Comment: Again: Obviously. Oracle will not just give you all map data for free. You need to buy it.

Also: https://www.peakindicators.com/blog/obiee-11g-and-maps-frequently-asked-questions-faq

Comment: so to display more cities,it should  to buy a map from oracle

Comment: Have you read Tony's blog? There are multiple providers. NAVTEQ had good material. But as he states you even pay for Google's stuff. No card material worth using is ever free.

Comment: https://www.peakindicators.com/blog/obiee-11g-and-maps-frequently-asked-questions-faq


Same as I had already pasted above